# What is the correct HTTP status code for a child entity that is not found?

Tags: http

Say I've got a resource

```
/Products/123
```

And each `Product` has an associated `Supplier` entity in the back end database. POST and PUT requests must specify a supplier ID, which is then used to fetch a Supplier entity from the database.

What should be returned if a user issues a `PUT /Products/123`, which *is* found, but includes a bad Supplier ID, which is *not*?

`404 Not Found` with a message specifying which resource wasn't found?

`409 Conflict`?

Comment: Have you considered `422`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) status code may not be right choice because the resource that has not been found is not the target of your request:

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
> not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
> willing to disclose that one exists.  A `404` status code does not
> indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or
> permanent; the `410` (Gone) status code is preferred over `404` if the
> origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that
> the condition is likely to be permanent.

The [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code might be suitable for this situation, but is not be the best choice (I wouldn't define this situation as a *conflict*):

> [**6.5.8.  409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict. [..]

I would go for [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) status code with a clear description in the response payload:

> [**11.2.  422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

If [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) doesn't work for you, use the generic [`400`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1):

> [**6.5.1.  400 Bad Request**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
>
> The `400` (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

---

The following diagram (extracted from [this page](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/)) is pretty insightful when it comes to picking the most suitable `4xx` status code:

[image: Picking the right 4xx status code]

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there is a *correct* answer for this question (unless some REST purist can shed some light) but we currently use (or abuse...) `HTTP 400` (Bad Request) with an additional HTTP Header explaining the error (i.e. X-Error: Invalid supplier ID). However a [HTTP 422](https://httpstatuses.com/422) would also be a good alternative.
Statuses 404 or 409 would be confusing since there is no clear way to specify that the response is about a sub-resource.

Comment: Would it also be acceptable to return a 404 along with a message payload stating something like "A supplier with ID 999 was not found", thereby eliminating the confusion?

Comment: @BCA A message in the response payload is always welcome to make the things clear. The `404` is suitable when the requested resource cannot be found. In this situation, the requested resource (product with ID `123`) exists and can be found, but there's a problem with the request payload (that contains invalid data). Hence a `422` with a good description of the error would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I would use the 404 as mentioned prior:

[6.5.4. 404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
> not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
> willing to disclose that one exists. A 404 status code does not
> indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or
> permanent; the 410 (Gone) status code is preferred over 404 if the
> origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that
> the condition is likely to be permanent.

Because the product that you are looking for exists, but the Supplier ID not, so basically is like we are looking for you in a different city, you exist but not in that city, so we will say, hey we did not found you.

I believe that supplier and product they have a relationship and it is a hard relationship, that a product can not exist if you don't have a supplier for that product, so that means you can not update a product if you don't know it is supplier.