# HTTP status while POST with incorrect data (using id of resource which does not exist)

Tags: rest, http-status-codes, http-status-code-422

What would be the **correct HTTP status to return** when I am performing the POST request to create a new user, but one of its parameters is incorrect - the company id I am including with the user data doesn't exist in the database.

POST
data: {username: 'newuser', age: 99, **company_id: 34**}

**the company with id 34 does not exist in the database.**

I was thinking whether that could be:

- 400, kind of invalid data, but it is valid but nonexistent id
- 404 - but it is not so clear which resource does not exist
- 409, because it is kind of conflict and the user can resolve that by changing the company id
- 422?
- or  500 - because it is kind of database error while non existing id's are not allowed there

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### `400` or `422`

First of all, keep in min that it's a [client error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5), so [`5xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6) status codes are not suitable here. You should pick a [`4xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) status code then.

The most obvious options are [`400`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) and [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2):

- If the JSON is *syntactically invalid*, return [`400`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5).
- If JSON is *syntactically valid* but its *content is invalid*, return [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) to indicate that the request entity cannot be processed by the server.

See the following quote from the [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) (for your situation, just read *JSON* when it says *XML*):

> [**11.2.  422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

A similar situation was addressed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42135981/1426227).

---

For example purposes, the [GitHub API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/?#client-errors) also returns [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) if the content of the payload contains invalid values (but is syntactically valid):

> There are three possible types of client errors on API calls that
> receive request bodies:
>
> 1. Sending invalid JSON will result in a `400 Bad Request` response. [...]
> 2. Sending the wrong type of JSON values will result in a `400 Bad Request response`. [...]
> 3. Sending invalid fields will result in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response. [...]

---

[Michael Kropat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27581/michael-kropat) put together a [set of diagrams](https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html) that's pretty insightful when it comes to picking the most suitable status code. See the following diagram for `4xx` status codes:

[image: Picking the right 4xx status code]

Comment: What about this status connected to WebDAV? I have seen somewhere you should use it only if you support WebDAV capabilities.

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska Where is _somewhere_? WebDAV is a HTTP extensions and `422` is a valid HTTP status code [registered in IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml).

Comment: I generally advise people to avoid using the status codes associated with WebDAV unless they're actively using the WebDAV standard as the basis for their API; I think it's confusing to consumers to cherry-pick a specific (although appropriate) status code from an obscure standard, ignoring everything else about that standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: CassioMazzochiMolin, I have read it in this article: https://www.keycdn.com/support/422-unprocessable-entity/

Comment: @PaulTurner I was thinking about simplicity and clarity and 400 with a description 'invalid/incorrect company id'. The request just does not seem to have an invalid syntax problem.


Generally the POST request I described seems to be not a rare case and I don't see many 422 errors returned in APIs.

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska See the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/?#client-errors) for example. It returns `400` for invalid JSON and wrong type of JSON values and `422` for invalid fields.

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska `422` is also [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3291292/1426227) by Julian Reschke, one of the authors of the RFCs 7230-35, the documents that define the HTTP/1.1 protocol.

Answer (score 3):

`404 Not Found` is a problematic status to return for a `POST` request. It implies the resource you are sending the request to doesn't exist; the caller got the URL wrong.

The most obvious (and generic) answer is: `400 Bad Request`

This just indicates there is something wrong with your request (the fault lies with the caller not the server) and then express the specific detail of what went wrong in your response body. This is typically how request validation is handled.

---

The *ideal* answer is to make it so you add a user by sending a request to the company they are a member of:

```
POST /company/34
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "username": "newuser",
    "age": 99
}
```

This means the caller has to find a valid `company` resource to send the request to. If `company/34` doesn't exist, a `404 Not Found` response is appropriate; you tried adding a user to a company which does not exist.

This does mean your API has to be structured with resource semantics and a user has to belong to exactly one company.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this picture is very good, and I've used it many times.

[Which code should I return?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTpnp.png)

I'd go with 404. The resource could exist (not a format error) but it just doesn't (and hence can't be found).

Comment: Thank you, according to this picture I should use 422.

Comment: `404` makes no sense here.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin Would you mind trying to add something useful instead of just bashing senselessly, like why my reasoning was wrong?